# When is it absolutely necessary to make an explicit call to superclass' parameterized constructors and why so?

Tags: java, constructor

In other words,
If a superclass does not have a default constructor, any subclasses extending it must make an explicit call to one of the superclass' parameterized constructors. why so?

It would be nice if you could try explaining it using Java.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're proposing that a parameterized constructor should be called implicitly, or whether you're proposing that *no* superclass constructor is called?

Comment: More like, Can you help justifying the following sentence 'If a superclass does not have a default constructor, any subclasses extending it must make an explicit call to one of the superclass' parameterized constructors'?

Comment: Yes: it's justified by considering the downsides of alternatives, which I've outlined.

Comment: "If a superclass does not have a default constructor" there is a difference between the default constructor and an explicit constructor taking no arguments: the latter isn't considered a "default constructor". If the superclass has a no-args constructor (whether default or explicit), you will call that in the subclass if you don't invoke `super(...)`. If no such constructor exists, or you want to call a different constructor, you have to explicitly call that with `super(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your superclass has a field `something` and a constructor which initializes that field based on a passed parameter. You cannot create a child instance without properly initializing the super class. And if there is no default constructor the compiler cannot implicitly make the call. Instead it now it needs a parameter value to pass and the compiler cannot figure that value out on its own, instead you as the programmer need to explicitly state which parameter to pass to what super constructor.